# How to connect two vertices of two objects in python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects, vertices

I have two objects where I want to randomly link different vertices.  Is there a way to select two vertices and connect them if I know their coordinates?

Comment: Hello. Can you elaborate a bit more about what you want to do, add pictures for instance. If two objects, they need to be merged in one if you want to connect their vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but you can Shift-Click vertices in Edit Mode to select multiple of them. If you select 2, and then press "F", an Edge will be formed between them. If you select 3 or more and press "F", a Face will be formed between them.

Comment: As lemon says in his comment, this will only work if they are part of the same mesh.

Comment: I am new to blender so I may not be phrasing my question correctly.  I am trying to create an image entirely in code.  I am randomly distributing objects and now trying to connect them.  Ultimately I want to run physics simulations but for now I'm trying to create the model.